# Search for pages tagged with a tag title

Tags: aem, query-builder

In order to get pages tagged with a certain tag in AEM query builder, we will do as this doc (https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-2/sites/developing/using/querybuilder-api.html)

```
    path=/content/...
    type=cq:Page
    tagid=marketing:interest/product
    tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags
```

But how do we get pages that have the same tag title without using the whole tag's ID or full path above ?
For example

```
    path=/content/...
    type=cq:Page
    tagtitle=product
    tagid.property=jcr:content/cq:tags
```

Comment: When performing JCR queries in your back-end code, you should be using the name of the tag, not its title. Tags with the same title can be semantically different. At the same time, a single tag can have multiple, localized titles.

Comment: What the query should be when using tag name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like that:

**JCR like:**

```
path=/content/..
type=cq:Page
property=jcr:content/@cq:tags
property.value=%tagname
property.operation=like
```

This would search for cq:tags property with value that ends with "product".
See more about [jcr:like](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/1.0/6.6.5.1_jcr_like_Function.html)  function.

Another possible solution:

**Full text search:**

```
path=/content/somesite
type=cq:Page
fulltext.relPath=jcr:content/@cq:tags
fulltext=tagname
```

See more about [jcr:contains](https://docs.adobe.com/content/docs/en/spec/jcr/1.0/6.6.5.2_jcr_contains_Function.html) function